# Disabling click event handlers

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I am trying to basically disable the `click` event on a `<div>` temporarily.

I have tried the following ([preview](http://jsbin.com/ewinu)):

```
$('hello').observe('click', function (e) {
    e.stop();
});

$('hello').observe('click', function (e) {
    alert('click not stopped!');
});
```

However, when `#hello` is clicked, the alert box still appears.  I do not want the second attached handler to be called, and *I do not want to change the second handler*.

I will also accept a solution such as:

```
$('hello').observe('click', function (e) {
    alert('click not stopped!');
});

$('hello').disableEvent('click');

// Now, handler won't be called

$('hello').observe('click', function (e) {
    alert('click not stopped (2)!');
});

// New handler won't be called, either

$('hello').enableEvent('click');

// Now, handler will be called
```

I am using the Prototype.js framework.  This doesn't seem to be a browser-specific issue.

Comment: Have you looked into [CancelBubble](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/cancelBubbleExample.htm)? This can be used to effectively kill the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments to [roosteronacid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205273/disabling-click-event-handlers/3206139#3206139), I wrote an extension to `Event.observe`.  *Works in most browsers, but* ***not IE***.

```
// XXX HACK XXX
(function () {
    var handlerCache = $A([ ]);

    function findHandler(either) {
        var pair = handlerCache.find(function (pair) {
            return $A(pair).member(either);
        });

        return pair && pair[0];
    }

    function addHandler(handler) {
        function newHandler(e) {
            if (!e.halted) {
                handler.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }

        handlerCache.push([ handler, newHandler ]);

        return newHandler;
    }

    Event.observe = Event.observe.extended(function ($super, element, eventName, handler) {
        handler = findHandler(handler) || addHandler(handler);

        $super(element, eventName, handler);
    });

    Event.stopObserving = Event.stopObserving.extended(function ($super, element, eventName, handler) {
        handler = findHandler(handler) || handler;

        $super(element, eventName, handler);
    });

    Element.addMethods({
        observe: Event.observe
    });

    Event.prototype.halt = function () {
        this.halted = true;
    };
}());
```

*Note: `Function.prototype.extended` is a custom function which puts the original `Event.observe` in as `$super`.*

Answer (score 3):

When you assign handlers to events; you are basically just storing a set of functions to be executed when an event fires.

When an event fires, the handlers you've added are executed *in the order they we're added*. So if you we're to add three handlers to a div's click-event:

```
$("div").observe("click", function ()
{
    alert("one");
});

$("div").observe("click", function ()
{
    alert("two");
});

$("div").observe("click", function ()
{
    alert("three");
});
```

.. you would get three alerts ("one", "two" and "three") when the click event of the div element fires. Those three alerts will still get shown, if you put in:

```
$("div").observe("click", function (e)
{
    e.stop();
})
```

.. because you are only canceling the event for one particular handler. Not all associated handlers.

So what you will need to do is use a reference variable, which keeps track of wether the click event is allowed to fire:

```
var cancelClickEvent = true;

$("div").observe("click", function ()
{
    // if cancelClickEvent is true, return the function early, to
    // stop the code underneath from getting executed
    if (cancelClickEvent) return;

    // your code goes here
});
```

You will then need to implement the above if-clause in all your handlers.

Comment: Okay, now I understand a little better.  However, I really don't want to modify other handlers.  I'm considering overriding `Element.observe` to wrap the handler with a check for some flag on `Event`.  Would this work, maybe?

Comment: It's never a good idea to override core functionality--you never know what you might break.. And what are you gonna do when a new version comes around? Re-implement your modifications?.. What if the API changes?.. If you want a cleaner approach; use the disabled property on your div elements, instead of a global reference variable to determine if the event should be cancelled.

Comment: I wasn't going to use a global; I was going to use a flag on the event instance (which is passed among handlers).  I agree that overriding the core isn't a good idea, but I see little other options at the moment.

Comment: If you can somehow modify the Event objects prototype, without possibly breaking any core features; you have my blessings ;) ... Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the object's disabled property to true?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (`<div disabled="disabled">`), sadly.

Comment: it would be disabled="true", and it's html standard... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957067/div-disabled-or-greyed-out Edit: check the accepted answer, not the upvoted.